# OpenFlashChart Error #2032 with AJAX; but works with php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, open-flash-chart

Hi there I am playing with OpenFlash-Chart,
while some php graphs are displayed properly,
I get the following error with my latest code in javascript:

```
Open Flash Chart
IO ERROR
Loading test data
Error #2032
This is the URL that I tried to open:../../data-files/y-axis-auto-steps.txt
```

I understood, that this is a general error-msg, which shows up e.g. if data isn't sent properly to ofc.

The call comes from this function:

```
 function open_flash_chart_data(){
     return JSON.stringify(data);
     }


 function plot_graph(checkedBoxes, theitems, thetrack, thedates, thevalues, trackCount){
     top.restoreSession();
     $.ajax({ url: 'graph_include.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: { dates:  thedates, 
                      values: thevalues, 
                      items:  theitems, 
                      track:  thetrack, 
                      thecheckboxes: checkedBoxes
                    },
              dataType: "json",  
              success: function(returnData){
              // place the raw graph data in the data variable 
                        var data=returnData;
                         swfobject.embedSWF('open-flash-chart.swf',"graph"+trackCount, "650", "200", "9.0.0");
                $('#graph'+trackCount).show();  

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
      }); // end ajax query
 }
```

My function `plot_graph()` is called with proper variables, but I get Error #2032

My workaround:

in `graph_include.php`, which is called by AJAX, I write the `echo $chart->toPrettyString();` into a file called "`plot.json`", like this:

```
$fh = fopen("plot.json", 'w');    
$chartjson = $chart->toPrettyString(); 
fwrite($fh, $chartjson);
fclose($fh);
```

Then a changed the success callback into this, in order to fetch data from `plot.json`:

```
 success: function(returnData){
    // graph_include.php writes the $chart->toPrettyString();
    // into file "plot.json" inside of the track_anything folder
    // we just fetch these data from that file, as
    // var data=returnData
    // don't seem to work here
    // (open-flash-chart won't find var data for some reason)
        swfobject.embedSWF('open-flash-chart.swf', 
        "graph"+trackCount, "650", "200", "9.0.0","",{"data-file":"plot.json"});
```

This works just fine and I get a proper chart.

So, I guess Error 2032 must have something to do with my ajax-call...

Could please someone have a look on what I am doing wrong with ajax, because I need this javascript/ajax thing to get some vars which are passed to php...

Comment: Looks like you have a scope problem. You need to declare your data variable further up the chain and then set it from the ajax callback.

Comment: I tried it and wrote a "var data;" to very beginning of my file, before the AJAX-function, but that didn't work either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this will help:

outside of the ajax function, declair a variable like this:

```
 var flashvars = {};
```

inside the AJAX-success-call, write:

```
 success: function(returnData){
      // we need to set both
      // data and flashvars.ofc
      data=returnData;
      flashvars.ofc = returnData;
      swfobject.embedSWF('openflashchart/open-flash-chart.swf', 
      "graph"+trackCount, "650", "200", "9.0.0","",flashvars);
```

That works here...